# Oracle Database Query with Time Zones

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle,I found a query which is somewhat confusing.
Can someone please explain what is the meaning of below , what is being done to ENDTIME.

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(from_tz(CAST(END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP),to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM'))) as endTime
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `END_TIME` is a DATE column.

Working outwards from the innermost functions:

- `CAST(END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP)` converts the DATE to a TIMESTAMP - this adds fractional seconds (which will be zero), but no time zone information. For example, a date of 2022-01-04 06:30:45 would become 2022-01-04 06:30:45.000.
- `to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM')` gets the current system timestamp, which includes the system (not session) time zone, and converts just the time zone part to a string representation of that time zone offset, such as `'+08:00'`.
- `from_tz(CAST(END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP),to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM'))` converts the TIMESTAMP value from the first bullet to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, using the time zone offset from the second bullet, effectively doing `from_tz(timestamp '2022-01-04 06:30:45.000', '+08:00')`, so the value now becomes 2022-01-04 06:30:45.000 +08:00. (The overall expression would appear  to work without this step; but then you would be doing an *implicit* conversion using the session time zone, which could give a different answer, and different answers for different users.)
- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(from_tz(CAST(END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP),to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM')))` converts that time zone-aware value to its UTC equivalent, as a plain timestamp, effectively doing `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(timestamp '2022-01-04 06:30:45.000 +08:00')`, so the value now becomes 2022-01-03 22:30:45.000
- `as endTime` just gives that column expression an alias in the final result.

This still has an issue if the system has daylight savings time. Because the conversion is using the *current* system time zone offset, it will get different results if you run it at different times of year. Without knowing the system's time zone *region*, rather than just the offset, there isn't much you can do about that; and you can't get the region from `systimestamp`.

Comment: any other way in which i could convert END_TIME to UTC which works for all scenario's ?

Comment: @user3865748 - if you know that all `END_TIME` date values a supposed to be in, and are valid in, a specific time zone region then you can supply that instead - just change `to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM')` to that region, e.g. `'Europe/London'. But then that's hard-coded, which might be fine, unless the same code is/might be run on multiple DBs in different regions; then you'd need a way to supply the right value, such as a parameter look-up table. And you could have invalid values, depends how the column is populated.

Answer (score 1):

- `FROM_TZ()` attaches a time zone to a `TIMESTAMP` without time zone.
- `FROM_TZ()` works only on `TIMESTAMP`. `END_TIME` seems to be a `DATE` data type, that's the reason for `CAST(END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP)` (Note, neither `DATE` nor `TIMESTAMP` contain any time zone information)
- `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM')` returns the time zone of the database server's operating system
- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC()` transforms a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value to UTC Time

To summarize: `END_TIME` is a `DATE` value at the time zone of the database server's operating system. The statement converts it into UTC time.

As mentioned correctly by Alex, this query may have an issue with daylight saving times, see this example to visualize:

```
SELECT 
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM'))) AS END_TIME_1,
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE+150 AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZH:TZM'))) AS END_TIME_2,
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Zurich')) AS END_TIME_3,
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE+150 AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Zurich')) AS END_TIME_4 
FROM dual;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| END_TIME_1          | END_TIME_2          | END_TIME_3          | END_TIME_4          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 05.01.2022 13:59:35 | 04.06.2022 13:59:35 | 05.01.2022 13:59:35 | 04.06.2022 12:59:35 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```